# how to tie powerpoint bullet to related image for purposes of animation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I'm building a set of slides with bullets. I want to use "appearance" animations so I can step through the bullets with the space bar. On several slides, I have a screenshot image that I've positioned right after the bullet I want the image to be associated with. However, when I add appearance animations, the slide just displays all the screenshot images immediately, before any of the bullets appear. It seems like PowerPoint treats the images as "floating", and not associated with the bullets.

What can I do here?

One person in another forum suggested "try using a custom picture bullet for the text or using individual lines of text, each grouped with the screenshot image and each animated individually", but I don't understand these strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One person in another forum" here.  ;-)

Scratch the part about "custom picture bullet"; I think I misunderstood what you were after.  If I have it correctly, you have several lines of text that you want to have appear in an animated sequence and you want a screenshot image to appear at the same time the associated line of text appears.

You can't do that if all the text is in one text box; instead, add the text as a series of text boxes. For each text box, add the picture you want to have appear with it, group the picture and the text box, then animate the groups to appear one at a time.

You can't use one of the "click here" placeholder text boxes to do this, by the way.  They can't be grouped with other shapes.  Instead, use Insert | Text Box for the first one, format it to taste, then duplicate it to create the remaining text boxes. Saves a lot of formatting time.

Comment: Related but different question: How do I get the text box bullets to use the same bullet style as the "Click here" box?  The default is a green solid triangle, but in the text box, it's a completely different list of bullet icons.

Comment: Considering how fast you found this posting, after the other one :) , you'll probably already have seen this, but I posted this for that last question: http://superuser.com/questions/1184163/in-powerpoint-how-do-i-get-the-bullet-icon-in-a-text-box-to-use-the-same-icon-a .

Comment: ;-)  Hadn't seen it, but Format Painter was going to be my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In Powerpoint 2016 I am able to add the order of the picture:

1. Go to animation tab
2. Click the image
3. Pick an effect
4. Pick the order when it should appear

Answer (score 0):

If the text is pretty much finalized, you can achieve a visually-equivalent result without animation. This is done by duplicating the base slide that includes the bulleted list. For each of the copies, you'll need to color the text that "hasn't appeared yet" using the same color as the background. Each slide would have only the image that corresponds with the latest bullet point. You'll still see the upcoming bullets in each slide, but not their text.

The disadvantage of this is that changes to the text will have to be made across slides, but it still may be easier than having to align and manage the animation for text boxes. Also, if the images are placed in the same location on the slide, managing them in separate slides is easier than managing them with animation.