# In powerpoint, how do I get the bullet icon in a text box to use the same icon as in the "Click here" box?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint-2013

Using PowerPoint 2013.

I have a set of slides with mostly ordinary slides with green bullets.  They all use the "default" bullet style using a green filled triangle.  They all use "Appearance" animations so I can make each bullet appear one by one.

On a couple of slides, I have to construct it differently because some of the bullets are immediately followed by screenshot images, and I want the image to appear when the bullet appears.  So, I deleted the "Click here" placeholder and created text boxes for each bullet line, inserted the images, and grouped the image to the bullet above it.  Functionally, this works fine.

What's slightly annoying is that the available bullet styles in a text box are different from the styles available in the main placeholder.  I want all bullets to use the same style, whether they came from the placeholder or a text box.

How can I copy the entire bullet style from a placeholder (icon and color) into the bullet of a text box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the [Format Painter](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-formatting-using-the-Format-Painter-b9fe82ea-c0a0-41de-837b-d2f15dd41ea9#__toc307480776) tool to copy the icon and formatting changes you have made to it.

Or when you go to paste it, right click and use the option you need under paste options.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. I first clicked on the bullet with the bullet style I want to copy (I also tried selecting all the text in the bullet). I then clicked "Format Painter". I then went to the other slide that has the text box that I want to have the same style.  I clicked on it. The help info just says to "select something else to automatically apply the formatting". I don't know what I'm supposed to do here.

Comment: Well, now I'm confused.  I tried it again, and now when I click in the second field, the bullet icon changes to what I want.  Dunno why it didn't work before.  I tried it several times.